# What is "Error configuring an instance of JdbcSinkConnectorConfig" with Debezium JdbcSinkConnector

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, debezium

I met an error when use Debezium JdbcSinkConnector. That is an error I cannot find on the internet.

I met the error that

```
    tasks:
      - id: 0
        state: FAILED
        trace: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error configuring an instance of JdbcSinkConnectorConfig; check the logs for details
    at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorConfig.validate(JdbcSinkConnectorConfig.java:481)
    at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.start(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:236)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

So what is this error, and how can I fix this?

below is my spec of yaml file:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  labels: strimzi.io/cluster: connect-cluster
  name: tuyen
  namespace: strimzi
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
  config:
    auto.create: false
    auto.evolve: true
    connection.url: jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:port/dbname
    connection.username: kafka
    connection.password: kafka
    database.dbname: KafkaDest
    database.server.name: TESTINGUserInfo
    insert.mode: upsert
    pk.fields: AutoId
    pk.mode: record_key
    table.name.format: UserInfo
    time.precision.mode: connect
    topics: test.KafkaSrc.dbo.UserInfo
    transforms: TimestampConverter,ExtractField
    transforms.ExtractField.field: AutoId
    transforms.ExtractField.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
    transforms.TimestampConverter.field: UpdateTime
    transforms.TimestampConverter.format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type: Timestamp
    transforms.TimestampConverter.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
tasksMax: 1
```

Comment: That's not how sql server connection string should look, so might wanna start there

Comment: Ok, I fixed that to "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:port;databaseName="dbname" ", but the error is still the same

Comment: Where did you see that database name should have quotes around it? And did you check logs for details?

Comment: I did not use quotes around it, i only want to mention that "dbname" is the name of db llike this jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:port;databaseName=User and "dbname"=User

Comment: Ok, well, then try creating a simple Class that just connects with this connection string and selects some stuff, and see if that works. If yes, then as it says on the tin, you should check the logs

Comment: Aside... `transforms.TimestampConverter.format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` can break depending on your SQL Server's `DATEFORMAT` settings. A safer format would be (based on the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` docs) something like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` so that there's a `T` separating the date and time portions. You'll also want to use `transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type: string` because `Timestamp` produces numeric formats of Unix epoch-based time.

Comment: So when it says, _Error configuring an instance of JdbcSinkConnectorConfig; check the logs for details_, did you check the logs for details?